# What is the best way to make a zoom event automatically trigger a resize event?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, resize, zooming, dom-events

I have some resize code, but it does not seem to get triggered for a zoom event.  I have had zoom code trigger resize code before, and know a little bit about situations that cause a zoom event to trigger a resize, however I would like to get more explanation.

What is the best way to force a zoom event Ctrl++ or Ctrl+- to cause a onresize call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't like the answer. I suggest you don't do this. There is no native way to detect it, as in window.onzoom or anything like that. You would have to set up an interval timer and continually do DOM testing of box sizes compared to font sizes. And newer browsers zoom differently than older browsers. IE6 just increases the font size while FF3.5 increases the size of the page and re-wraps to to fit.

The recommendation is to allow the browser to act as intended and set up your CSS styles appropriately with EM tags for sizes.

Comment: I don't have to worry about IE6.

Comment: I think there are other tricks.  I know you can sometimes detect a zoom. It is something like if a div gets resized it triggers a resize event, or something, like that.

Comment: I mean zoom does sometimes trigger a resize event, so I just have to figure out exactly why.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys, I have a solution I like better than either of yours.  Basically, make a wrapper div arround all you html source.

<div style="height:100%;width:100%" onresize="youResizeCode()"></div>

It works great for me.  I am basically using it for FF3 and IE8, I am not sure which browsers will work with this.

Grae

Comment: Resize events only fire on elements in IE. Other browsers only use the window. This should not be accepted, as it doesn't work cross-browser.  See http://jsfiddle.net/zachleat/kj5nK/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536959(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My method only works for zoom in, also.  Zoom out does have to resize the wrapper div, so it will not trigger an event.  I think a timeout interval is the best way to go about things.